# Cannot download files with firefox 43

Tags: firefox

I have two User accounts on my machine, user1 and user2.

In user1 account, Firefox downloads fail: if I click on a link to a something like a zip file, or choose 'Save link as...', no dialog window appears and the download fails.

The same problem occurs in Safe Mode, or in a fresh Firefox profile.

It also occurs in a Guest session.

In user2 account, where Firefox already had a profile before the problem started to appear, things work as usual.

Versions: Firefox 43.0, Ubuntu 14.04

Ideas welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using different download manager? You can install flashgot add-on for Firefox and then you can choose your download managers like uGet or wGet.

Comment: Remember: the problem occurs in a fresh FF profile and in a guest session.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug filed for this issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1527884

Answer (score 0):

I would say start with the obvious:

1. Check if the configured download directory in FireFox settings DOES exist.
2. You have write permission for this directory

Comment: The download dir is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Refresh Firefox feature can fix many issues by restoring Firefox to its factory default state while saving your essential information. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

Hope it helps.